# How do I show that a transformation is a symmetry of the Lagrangian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, harmonic-oscillator, complex-numbers

Hello All I have the following question see part (b). I have already done part a and my answer is  $L=\frac{m}{2}\dot{z}\bar{\dot{z}}-\frac{k}{2}z\bar{z}$.

I have no idea how to go about part b, I know that $\delta L$ has to be zero I think but other than that I have no clue.

[image]

Comment: $$e^x \approx 1 + x + \frac 1 2 x^2 + O(x^3)$$

Comment: $$z\mapsto e^{i\omega}z$$ and $$\overline{z}\mapsto e^{-i\omega}\overline{z}$$. Can you proceed using this?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/

Comment: Plug it in . . . . . . L .

Answer (score 1):

> ... I have already done part a and my answer is  $L=\frac{m}{2}\dot{z}\bar{\dot{z}}-\frac{k}{2}z\bar{z}$.

> I have no idea how to go about part b

Part "b" is to show that $z\to z' = e^{i\omega} z$ is a symmetry of the Lagrangian.

This means you need to show that that form of the Lagrangian does not change when you make this substitution.

You have a Lagrangian function:
$$
L(z) = \frac{m}{2}\dot{z} \dot{\bar{z}}-\frac{k}{2}z\bar z\;,
$$
where $\bar z$ is the complex conjugate of $z$.

So, plug $z e^{i\omega}$ into the function and show that:
$$
L(z e^{i\omega}) = L(z)
$$

Comment: Alternatively, note that $z\to z' = e^{i\omega} z$ is a rotation of co-ordinates in the x-y plane, which leaves velocity and hence KE (the first term in $L(z)$) unchanged, and also leaves $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ unchanged.